# How to Code a Screen capture program for minecraft?

Tags: java, screen, minecraft, screen-capture

I'm a Novice programmer with many devices to use for coding, i'm asking for a answer to what language i should use or best way to implement something that captures my windows 10 screen on minecraft(could be used elsewhere) and will see form past inputs if something has changed and will log me back in, say when a server crashes. This is so i can continue doing a specific task afk.

I've found low amounts of resources on something so specific that i'm doing but I know fellow gamer's would be glad to have something like this for afking in general.

OS- Windows 10
-Language I'm familiar with Python and Java, willing to learn a language if it helps

Comment: Yea, no. As much as I'm for programming your heart out, this seems blatantly useless. Just use a generic screen recorder like OBS and save yourself the effort. It's really not fun to code all that stuff, especially if you are planning to add extra functionality

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice, I didn't know OBS had the features for things like that.